# Can't use docker/podman on fresh Centos8

Tags: docker, centos8, podman

I have a fresh CentOS 8 machine. Not knowing about "podman" I installed docker: `yum install docker`. This actually installs podman 1.0.5.

I can't run any images:

```
devrisenshine2 [wiretap_wrapper] % podman run -it --rm alpine sh
error creating libpod runtime: Error running podman info while refreshing state: exit status 1
devrisenshine2 [wiretap_wrapper] % sudo podman run -it --rm alpine sh
container create failed: cannot specify gid= mount options for unmapped gid in rootless containers
: internal libpod error
```

I understand /etc/sub?id can be related to this:

```
devrisenshine2 [wiretap_wrapper] % cat /etc/subuid
garyo:100000:65536
devrisenshine2 [wiretap_wrapper] % cat /etc/subgid
garyo:100000:65536
devrisenshine2 [wiretap_wrapper] % ls -l /etc/sub?id
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19 Jan 10 15:32 /etc/subgid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19 Jan 10 15:32 /etc/subuid
```

Googling around I figured I need to install some other stuff:

```
sudo dnf install -y @container-tools
```

that installs buildah, ocio-umount, and skopeo, but nothing changes. I rebooted after that as well.

I'm not sure what to do next. I've used docker for years but not podman. Maybe I missed a config step?

It looks like there may be some fixes in later versions of podman, but on this machine I don't want to install all the build tools and dependencies to build podman from scratch.

Oh, here's my `podman info`:

```
devrisenshine2 [wiretap_wrapper] % podman info
ERRO[0000] cannot setup namespace using newuidmap: exit status 1 
devrisenshine2 [wiretap_wrapper] % sudo podman info
host:
  BuildahVersion: 1.6-dev
  Conmon:
    package: podman-1.0.5-1.gitf604175.module_el8.0.0+194+ac560166.x86_64
    path: /usr/libexec/podman/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 1.14.0-dev, commit: db4132fdf7a7a29546679331f7119a745266f613-dirty'
  Distribution:
    distribution: '"centos"'
    version: "8"
  MemFree: 1359548416
  MemTotal: 1585446912
  OCIRuntime:
    package: runc-1.0.0-55.rc5.dev.git2abd837.module_el8.0.0+58+91b614e7.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: 'runc version spec: 1.0.0'
  SwapFree: 2122317824
  SwapTotal: 2122317824
  arch: amd64
  cpus: 2
  hostname: devrisenshine2
  kernel: 5.3.13-1-pve
  os: linux
  rootless: false
  uptime: 1m 40s
insecure registries:
  registries: []
registries:
  registries:
  - registry.redhat.io
  - quay.io
  - docker.io
store:
  ConfigFile: /etc/containers/storage.conf
  ContainerStore:
    number: 0
  GraphDriverName: overlay
  GraphOptions: null
  GraphRoot: /var/lib/containers/storage
  GraphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: extfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  ImageStore:
    number: 2
  RunRoot: /var/run/containers/storage
```

What might I be missing?

Comment: I don't understand why I still see messages about rootless containers when I'm running in sudo.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue.